# Не работают списковые элементы ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Хочу использовать `asp:CheckBoxList`, но браузер выдаёт ошибку:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'matches' on 'Element': 
>   'A ASP:CHECKBOXLIST' is not a valid selector.

```
<form method="get" action="">
    <h3>Критерії вибору:</h3>
    <p>Тип</p>
    <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="CheckboxList1" RepeatColumns="3">
        <asp:ListItem Selected="true">Option 1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Option 2</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
    <p>Ціна</p>
    <label for="minPrice">Від:</label>
    <input type="number" name="minPrice" id="minPrice" value="@ViewBag.min"/>
    <label for="maxPrice">до:</label>
    <input type="number" name="maxPrice" id="maxPrice" value="@ViewBag.max"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Пошук"/>
</form>
```

Помогите решить проблему.

Comment: Приведите пример кода.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь использовать контролы ASP.NET WebForms на представлении ASP.NET MVC. Это разные фреймворки, их нельзя смешивать.

Comment: @kmv их можно смешивать, но не в этом контексте.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На представлении в asp.net mvc нельзя использовать контролы из asp.net webforms, Надо либо вручную написать `html select/option` либо использовать `Razor Syntax`. Примеры:

### HTML  Tag

```
<select id="Cars" name="Cars">
  <option value="0">Volvo</option>
  <option value="1">Saab</option>
  <option value="2">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="3">Audi</option>
</select>
```

### Razor:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult SelectCategory() {
    List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Volvo", Value = "0"});
    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Saab", Value = "1" });
    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Mercedes", Value = "2", Selected = true });
    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Audi", Value = "3" });
    ViewBag.Cars= items;
    return View();
}
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Cars")
```